# How to show the shell script's output on the views in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to run python script in my controller,
and the task may spend 2 minutes.
I can output the progress under command line , just use print.
but I have no idea hot to print the progress information in to the view to let users know the progress.

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html)

**controller**

```
class PostsController
  def index
    # your python script
    render stream: true
  end
end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head><title>  <%= provide :title, "Main" %></title></head>
  <body><%= yield %></body>
</html>
```

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= content_for :title, " your python results" %>
```